# Import previous commands to edited command

Tags: vim, shell, zsh, vimscript

I'm playing with zsh to change image modification time according to the 'Date/Time Original' exif attribute.

For this I one command I do:

`PDATE=$(exiftool -p '$DateTimeOriginal' $PIC | sed 's/[: ]//g')
touch -t $(echo $PDATE | sed 's/\(..$\)/\.\1/') $PIC`

I got some images with wrong 'Date/Time Original' value, so these images wasn't processed.

So I'm working on getting the date from the images filename and I got

```
for i in `grep -E -o 'IMG\S+jpg' logfile`; do 
dte=$(echo $i  | grep -E -o '20.{13}' | tr -d '_'); 
touch -t $dte $i; 
done
```

where logfile is a file containing exiftool messages of not correct arribute value etc.

Now the second snippet last command is not working because I need to make the sed substitution as in the first snippet.

My question is: while being in the zsh vi interactive mode, how can I get the access to the first snippet that is in history, without losing the content of the current command?

I'd imagine editing current command in vi (as I can do it when I press the 'v' character in the zsh vi control mode), getting history command listed and choosing one of them and it will be pasted in the line below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using zsh in the vi mode.

To solve your problem we divide the problem in two parts

**1. part - print command history lines matching a pattern**

For this we create a file `~/bin/history-print-regexp.sh` 
containing:

```
#!/bin/zsh
# command 'regular-expression' number-of-lines(counting from the end of the file)
nmbr=15
if [ "$#" -eq 2 ]; then
    nmbr=$2
fi
if [ "$#" -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "You need at least one argument"
    echo "Usage command regexp outputlinesCount"
fi
#tac - reverse print , grep -E - use extended regexp, cut -d ';' use ; as delimiter
#and print second field (-f 2), uniq -u print only unique lines
tac  ~/.histfile | grep -E $1 |  cut -d ';' -f 2 | uniq -u | head -n $nmbr
```

Now we need to get it working together with your present command. For this we do:

While being in the zsh vi normal mode you press the `v` button twice and the vi window opens.

In your ~/.vimrc file you put this function

```
function! ShowHistoryMatching(pattern)
10new
exe 'r!' . "history-print-regexp.sh " . a:pattern
call cursor(1,1)
endfunction

:cnoremap ch call ShowHistoryMatching
```

Use of this script is, while being in the zsh total vi editor editing your present command you press `:ch` which is extended to :call ShowHistoryMatching
and you add ("pattern") to this and press Enter and the results open in the window above. From there you can easily copy a desired line to your second window.

`C-w,q` closes a window
`C-w,j` goes to the window below.

Answer (score 2):

There is [zsh-cmd-architect](https://github.com/psprint/zsh-cmd-architect) created specifically to do what you describe. It displays you current command, allows to move blocks of it left and right, and also displays searchable history, from which you can choose blocks of commands there.